# use different odbc conector to connect mysql server

Tags: mysql, odbc, license

We found out Mysql odbc connector is released under gplv2 license. We have a commercial application (in c#) that connects to mysql (using Mysql.data) so we are supposed not to use mysql odbc connector because we would have to release our source code.

How can I connect to MySQL usign a method that does not involve using a gplv2 connector in order we dont have to publish our source code under the same license ?

Answer (score 0):

My employer, CData Software makes an ODBC Driver for MySQL: http://www.cdata.com/drivers/mysql/odbc/

Since you're working in C#, you might also want to take a look at our ADO.NET Provider for MySQL: http://www.cdata.com/drivers/mysql/ado/